# Parse CFML tags in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, wordpress, coldfusion

**Background**:

I have been running [a site](http://www.gastronomicfightclub.com/) on the blogger platform for the past 5 years.  I was using the option of hosting the site on my own server, publishing via FTP.  My server is running ColdFusion, so I decided to take advantage of that.  I created Coldfusion custom tags that provided additional functionality and included those in many of may posts -- to be clear, the *body* of my posts.  Google decided to shut off access to this FTP publishing option.  I took that news as an excuse to move to WordPress.  Now I have to figure out what to do about all of those ColdFusion tags in my posts.

**Problem**:

I'd like to not loose the functionality provided by the custom tags I have embedded into my posts.  My primary question is what's the best way to add functionality to a PHP site using custom tags?  My initial plan was to try parsing the page to find the  tags, then write a PHP class to basically mimic the functionality that was provided by the Coldfusion file.  I don't know much about PHP, so I'm not sure what tools or libraries are out there to facilitate that.  Or if it's just a foolish idea.  These are not well formed XML files, so I need something fairly robust.

**Example**:

I use the following tag:

```
<cf_taglinks>Tag1, Tag2, Tag3</cf_taglinks>
```

to generate a series of `<a..>Tag#</a>` elements that link to technorati or whatever I decide (thus the benefit of having a custom tag - very easy to change behaviors).  The solution for this problem could really be able to handle any link, so if I have a `<stackoverflowLink post="3944091"/>` tag, I should be able to translate that into

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3944091/" 
     target="_blank">Stackoverflow Question: 3944091</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I'm leaning towards the [Custom Tags](http://buggedcom.co.uk/projects/CustomTags.zip) library [mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220022/creating-custom-html-tags-for-cms/3220078#3220078) as the answer.  One of the best features is support for buried or nested tags like the code block below:

```
<ct:upper type="all">
    This text is transformed by the custom tag.<br />
    Using the default example all the characters should be made into uppercase characters.<br />
    Try changing the type attribute to 'ucwords' or 'ucfirst'.<br />
    <br />
    <ct:lower>
        <strong>ct:lower</strong><br />
        THIS IS LOWERCASE TEXT TRANSFORMED BY THE ct:lower CUSTOM TAG even though it's inside the ct:upper tag.<br />
        <BR />
    </ct:lower>
</ct:upper>
```

I highly recommend downloading the zip file and looking through the examples it contains.

Comment: Where was this when [I was looking for a similar system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723752/where-do-i-start-when-writing-a-new-scripting-language)?

Comment: Since I'm using WordPress, I decided to try to use short codes ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API ) since it was functionality already built in.  The problem with shortcodes that I haven't been able to resolve yet is doing a 3 part code, such as [if][else][endif].

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend *against* using shortcodes to create custom markup for the reasons outlined here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/05/02/dealing-with-shortcode-madness

Comment: @EAMann - I certainly get his arguments, however: A) This is my own template for my personal use, never to be distributed, so I'm not worried about lock-in.  B) My short codes are performing complex server side logic, not simple HTML replacement, so I couldn't replace with HTML if I wanted to.  `However`, if I could have gotten the Custom Tags library to work, I think that's a better way to go to prevent WordPress lock-in.

Comment: Actually, you had me convinced at point A. So long as it's not being distributed, it's up to you. I just shudder when people add a lot of custom shortcodes to anything they give away ...

Comment: @EAMann I get that, but when they do, aren't they also giving away the source code for handling those short codes?  I would think you would be able to port to a different theme and just bring the short code functions over.  I'm still very new to WordPress, so I'm not sure what's available and what's not.

Comment: A developer would be able to, yes.  And end-user with no PHP skills wouldn't be able to. So if you're distributing shortcode-heavy systems to non-technical users, you're doing them a disservice because they can't *not* use your system once they've started using it.